# retrieve people/organization information from linked in

Tags: javascript, api, social-networking, linkedin-api

hi I am involved in a development of web app, where I have to retrieve information of people or organization from linkedin, dynamically.Suppose user A can search for Organization and user B can search for particular person.

I have gone the throough the linked in API's but was not able to figure it out how to implement it.
I am using Linkedin javascript API

Kindly help me

Comment: @Anders : I have used linked in people search api, but by default its showing the standard results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LinkedIn API is a two-step process. First, get the user of your web app to authorize the app to access their LinkedIn information. This means setting up your app on LinkedIn as follows:

https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Once you have that set-up, you can then query the LinkedIn API using JavaScript (I assume JavaScript is the language/method you want to use, as you tagged it).

You can adjust the results coming back, per the documentation, by using facets and parameters. For instance, to perform a [people search](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapipeoplesearch) that returns all user's named Barack and their profile headline and summary, you'd do something like:

```
IN.API.PeopleSearch()
    .fields(["headline", "summary"])
    .params({"first-name":"Barack"})
    .result(function(result) {
        alert JSON.stringify(result)
    })
```

`headline` and `summary` are [profile fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) that you specify - you can change these to pull the information you need.

*Update - including code to perform a company search.*

To perform a Company Search using the JavaScript API, you'd use the [IN.API.Raw()](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiraw) method:

```
IN.API.Raw("/company-search:(facets,companies:(id,name,universal-name,website-url))")
  .result( function(result) { /* handle result */ } )
  .error( function(error) { /* handle error */ } );
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but how do I search organization information ??/ can u help me in this

Comment: If you want to use the JavaScript API, you use the IN.API.Raw() method, as I've edited my answer to include.